# Remove reference of a DLL - IIS

Tags: iis, dll

Good night.

I am having an annoying problem with a DLL.

Well, i needed to make a test with two different versions of a DLL on an application on IIS.

I renamed the original dll **Primavera.ERPOnline.Bso.Proxy.dll** to **_Primavera.ERPOnline.Bso.Proxy.dll**, and copy the new version to the folder.

After all the tests i removed the new dll and renamed the **_Primavera.ERPOnline.Bso.Proxy.dll** to the original name.

I made an iisreset, and try to initialize the application but for some reason i get an error, and i cannot start correctly the application:

> Exception message: Could not load file
>   or assembly
>   '_Primavera.ERPOnline.Bso.Proxy' or
>   one of its dependencies. The process
>   can not access the file because it is
>   being used by another process.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020

What do i need to do to "delete" that referece to that dll?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you shutdown the server before renaming the dll file?

Comment: As i remember, no. I made all without restarting. But now i have already restarted and the error remains.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: This was not enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the process explorer utility from sysinternals to check which process is using that file.

http://technet.microsoft.com/hi-in/sysinternals/bb896653%28en-us%29.aspx

Comment: That's the problem Gaurav. I've already used it. But for some reason it never finds it! :\

Comment: This is very strange. I delete the dll from the bin folder and it says that it doens't find the "Primavera.ERPOnline.Bso.Proxy". But, if i have the dll in the bin, what it doesn't find is the "_Primavera.ERPOnline.Bso.Proxy".

Comment: The process in use is System with PID 4.

Comment: You need to find using System Utilities what PID 4 is in your system??